# Samsung S6 BLE not Scanning

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, samsung-mobile

I am working on an Android App that has BLE communication.
All it does is scan for devices, and once I find a device with a specific name, I trigger a flow in the app.
For that I am doing the following:

1) init the scanner and start scanning with SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY (and no filters)

```
BluetoothManager bluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
BluetoothAdapter  mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter()
BluetoothLeScanner mLEScanner = mBluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();
ScanSettings scanSettings = new ScanSettings.Builder().setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY).build();
mLEScanner.startScan(null,scanSettings,this.scanCallback);
```

2) this is the scanCallback:

```
private ScanCallback scanCallback = new ScanCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onScanResult(int callbackType, final ScanResult result) {
        super.onScanResult(callbackType, result);
        //Do logic
    }

    @Override
    public void onScanFailed(int errorCode) {
        super.onScanFailed(errorCode);
        Log(R.string.ble_log_scanning_failed,String.valueOf(errorCode));
        }
};
```

**Problem**

The above code is working on all devices I tested on Except the Samsung Galaxy S6.

On the S6 it works 50% of times. But at times the phone will stop responding to any BLE devices. The callback is never called (not success nor failure). It's like the device stopped scanning for some reason. I tried to make it start scan every minute just for testing and it didn't work. Once it stop, it stop for good (sometimes restarting the phone fix the problem, but not always)

Any idea what might be the cause of this issue? anyone encountered similar problems?

Edit: To answer the comment:
Android version 6.0.1
After each successful scan, I stop the scanning, do the logic then start scanning again.

Thanks

Comment: Can you add more details such as Android version? Also, do you have any additional code that stops the current scan or are you just starting several scans without stopping the previous? Can you try with the default scan mode?

Comment: @dustedrob added an edit. I tried with the default mode, in vain. Thanks

Comment: Interesting, i have used the S6 for scanning and i can confirm that it does work. If it works after turning off and on the bluetooth antenna then there might be something wrong with you start/stop scan logic. Do you have more code you can share?